# My discord bot only sees its own messages

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I recently started making a discord bot on discord.net which has the functionality of correspondence with Chat GPT. But I ran into the problem that he only sees his messages and responds to them, I attached an example.[User :    Bot:*answer*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w37wi.png)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ChatGPT.Net;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;

public class Program
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private ChatGpt _chatGpt;
    private bool _isChatting;
    private Queue<string> _messageHistory;
    private List<LogMessage> _logMessages;
    private Dictionary<ulong, List<string>> _userMessageHistory = new Dictionary<ulong, List<string>>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _chatGpt = new ChatGpt("");
        _isChatting = false;
        _messageHistory = new Queue<string>();
        _logMessages = new List<LogMessage>();

        _client.Log += Log;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "");
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        _logMessages.Add(arg);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleMessageAsync;

        _client.Ready += async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Бот подключен!");

            try
            {
                var startChatCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
                    .WithName("startchat")
                    .WithDescription("Начать чат с ChatGPT");
                await _client.Rest.CreateGlobalCommand(startChatCommand.Build());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка при создании команды 'startchat': {exception.Message}");
            }

            try
            {
                var endChatCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
                    .WithName("endchat")
                    .WithDescription("Завершить текущий чат с ChatGPT");
                await _client.Rest.CreateGlobalCommand(endChatCommand.Build());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка при создании команды 'endchat': {exception.Message}");
            }
        };

        _client.InteractionCreated += async interaction =>
        {
            if (interaction is SocketSlashCommand slashCommand)
            {
                await SlashCommandHandler(slashCommand);
            }
        };
    }
    private async Task HandleMessageAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            if (_isChatting)
            {
                _messageHistory.Enqueue(message.Content);
                string chatInput = string.Join("\n", _messageHistory);

                string chatOutput = await _chatGpt.Ask(chatInput);

                Console.WriteLine($"Пользователь: {message.Content}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Бот: {chatOutput}");

                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Пользователь:") + $" {message.Content}");
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Бот:") + $" {chatOutput}");

                _messageHistory.Enqueue(chatOutput);
                if (_messageHistory.Count > 3)
                {
                    _messageHistory.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка при обработке сообщения: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


    private async Task SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command)
    {
        var channel = command.Channel;
        switch (command.Data.Name)
        {
            case "startchat":
                await StartChatCommand(command.Data, channel);
                break;
            case "endchat":
                await EndChatCommand(command.Data, channel);
                break;
        }
    }

    private async Task StartChatCommand(SocketSlashCommandData commandData, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
    {
        if (!_isChatting)
        {
            _isChatting = true;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат начат");
        }
        else
        {
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат уже идет");
        }
    }

    private async Task EndChatCommand(SocketSlashCommandData commandData, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
    {
        if (_isChatting)
        {
            _isChatting = false;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат окончен");
        }
        else
        {
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат окончен. Напишите /startchat для начала");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Сохраненные логи:");
        foreach (var logMessage in _logMessages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
    }

    private Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {


            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            if (_isChatting)
            {
                _messageHistory.Enqueue(message.Content);
                string chatInput = string.Join("\n", _messageHistory);

                string chatOutput = await _chatGpt.Ask(chatInput);

                Console.WriteLine($"Пользователь: {message.Content}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Бот: {chatOutput}");

                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Пользователь:") + $" {message.Content}");
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Бот:") + $" {chatOutput}");

                _messageHistory.Enqueue(chatOutput);
                if (_messageHistory.Count > 3)
                {
                    _messageHistory.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I enabled MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT in the settings and in the bot code, I also found that my code does not seem to delete message.content in any way, and the bot simply does not see it.
How can I solve this problem?
(If you don't understand what I wrote, then I'm sorry, I used Google Translator)

Comment: adding var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
}            }; didn't help

Comment: i added Console.WriteLine($"{arg}"); in HandleMessageAsync and I found out that he was receiving messages from users, but they were all empty. And I also removed the second message handler MessageReceivedAsync